# INDEX / MATCH using date range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to pull Routes based on whether the date is within a certain range.

I want to pull column M and fill column D based on these conditions:

Column K is between or equal to columns B and C
Based on things I have seen on the internet, I figured an array formula with INDEX/MATCH would be the best method, but so far have been rather stumped by this. the full sheet is much larger I have just made a smaller sample size to figure out the needed formula. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Image is of the data I have:

[Updated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqk4k.png)

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! If you already have some kind of formula, please share it with us, it is always much easier to help if we already have a basis to operate on.

Comment: Thanks for the response DarkDiamond! I don't have a formula, I cant figure out anything that would work. one of my coworkers suggested I try a INDEX/MATCH but I only have experience using VLOOKUP and was hoping someone here could provide some sort of insight

Comment: Seeing a sample of the expected outcome would be useful

Comment: I'm not sure that this makes sense yet. Column K has multiples of the same dates, e.g. two items dated Apr.16. Which should be used to determine the route? Will the bus suddenly become an issue? And on the subject of providing helpful sample data: why do you have all those blank columns in the sample? Can you not include the column letters? And why not provide text (rather than an image) so it would be easy to set up a spreadsheet? Finally, I second the nomad's comment.

Comment: Thanks Cybernetic.nomad and Mockman for the responses and helpful feed back. sorry for all the confusion. I have updated the picture to kind of show what I am attempting to achieve. I am not sure if it is even honestly possible. As for the blank columns they represent days that a bus did not run at all.